# Output of sorting results in html

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

There are problems, almost 20 hours without sleep)
Arraying the array outputs the result and everything is fine, but ...

Here is the parsing code for the array:

```
$html = '';
foreach ($nposts as $post){ 

if ($post['post_date'] != $last_date)
    {
    $html .= '<h3>'.$post['post_date'].'</h3>' ;
    } 

 $html .= '<div>id: ' . $post['ID'] . ' ' . $post['title'] . '</div><br>';
 $last_date = $post['post_date'];

};
echo $html;
```

As a result, I get this:

```
<h3>Wednesday 24 January 2018</h3>
<div>id: 1475 Title</div>
<br>
<div>id: 1455 Title</div>
<br>

<h3>Tuesday 23 January 2018</h3>
<div>id: 1388 Title</div>
<br>
<div>id: 1358 Title</div>
<br>
<div>id: 1315 Title</div>
<br>
<div>id: 1219 Title</div>
<br>
<div>id: 1198 Title</div>
<br>

<h3>Monday 22 January 2018</h3>
<div>id: 1063 Title</div>
<br>
<div>id: 996 Title</div>
<br>

<h3>Wednesday 01 January 2014</h3>
<div>id: 959 Title</div>
<br>
```

A little bit is not what I'm trying to get

I want to get this:

Separately the date, and all that apply to this date. Date as the title.
For example as news on sites.

01/22/2018

news 1
news 2
news 3

23.012018

news 1
news 2

```
<div class="one">   
<h3>Wednesday 24 January 2018</h3>
        <div class="two">id: 1475 Title</div>

        <div class="two">id: 1455 Title</div>

</div>

<div class="one">   
    <h3>Tuesday 23 January 2018</h3>
        <div class="two">id: 1388 Title</div>

        <div class="two">id: 1358 Title</div>

        <div class="two">id: 1315 Title</div>

        <div class="two">id: 1219 Title</div>

        <div class="two">id: 1198 Title</div>>

</div>

    ......
```

Help, I'm already too tired

Comment: So what's the issue? The `<br>` elements are showing up?

Comment: Go to sleep and when you wakeup your brain will work 20X faster and better and you will be able to find the solution or explain what you want better.

Comment: @AmrBerag - I was just thinking the same thing. The best expert advice for any developer.

Comment: @RQEST what is the expected output you need or please clearify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit complicated to do this in one loop, but the key is to know when you should close/open tag `<div class="one">`:

```
$html = '';
$last_date = '';

foreach ($nposts as $post) { 

    if ($post['post_date'] != $last_date) {

        $html .= $last_date !== '' ? '</div>' : '';
        $html .= '<div class="one">';
        $html .= '<h3>'.$post['post_date'].'</h3>';

    }

    $html .= '<div>id: ' . $post['ID'] . ' ' . $post['title'] . '</div>';

    $last_date = $post['post_date'];
}

$html .= '</div>';

echo $html;
```

Working Demo [Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a56868afccd1c479d720290e9634fabc2713ce83)

Comment: You are welcome, that's because your question is a little bit confusing, you should explain exactly what you want to achieve without adding things like 'almost 20 hours without sleep', the question should be specific to the problem that you are facing... read more about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)